# Combinations of strings of n lists

Tags: c#, .net, c++

I want to build all combinations of all strings in multiple lists. I have three parameters that are to be included. These are `"And"`, `"OR"`, `"Equal"`.

For example, I have the following three lists:

**list 1**: "India", "China", "Iran"

**list 2**: "Hindi", "English", "Chinese"

**list 3**: "Forest", "Desert", "River"

The output should be

```
India OR Hindi OR Forest
India AND Hindi AND Forest
India EQUAL Hindi EQUAL Forest
India OR China  OR Hindi
India AND China  AND Hindi
India  EQUAL China  EQUAL Hindi

Iran OR English OR River
Iran AND English AND River
Iran EQUAL English EQUAL River
```

and so on ...

The number of lists and the number of strings in the lists are not fixed.

I'd prefer a **recursive** solution.

Comment: "preferably use recursive function using C#!!!!" and with that it sounds like homework. Good luck.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't be helpful...

Comment: Here's an even better puzzler.  You've accepted 1 answer out of 12 asked.  What's the most efficient way to click accept?

Comment: "the number of lists are not fixed". So, as a first step, you can concatenate all the lists to a big one.

Comment: we are not in the business of writing your code for you, we need a starting point, what have you attempted so far?

Comment: @Andy Mikula: StackOverflow is not a code factory. The OP didn't make an effort to communicate their ideas/thoughts and ask specific pointed questions about where they are having difficulty.

Comment: @Jason its not a homework ... i want to achieve this through recursive function ... else its done from my side for fixed number of lists . ..

Comment: @Jason again, that doesn't mean you can't be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll first need to create combinations of the words and as the last step apply each of the keywords between them.

For each item in current list, if the list is last insert all keywords, else recurse with the next list of words as current.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply trying to create permutations. Donald E Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming Volume 4" would be a good place to read on theory of this, if you can't think of where to start with a solution (I agree with the others that this does look like it involves some homework - especially with the recursion reference. Why do you want recursion?) 
In Volume 4, you want Fascicle 2 "Generating All Tuples and Permutations" and Fascicle 3 "Generating All Combinations and Partitions".

I would approach it iteratively and not recursively. Then it really is a simple case of looping over each option for each "space" in the result. Why do you need recursion? Recursion will only add overhead imho.

Comment: I'd actually be interested to see the iterative version.